# How can i extract, In Linux, the files that contain the name of another file inside them

Tags: linux, bash, text, directory, grep

I have a directory (`/mydir/cdl`) with files with the extension cdl, e.g. `ADDDAY0.cdl`, `ADDDAY1.cdl`.
I would like to search in the set of files contained in another directory (`/otherdir/exe/`), which of them contain the file name .cdl as string eg. ADDDAY0.cdl.

I have used this script:

```
for fullfile in /mydir/cdl/*.cdl; do
   file_no_path=${fullfile##*/}
    base_name=${file_no_path%%.*}
    grep -H -orw '/otherdir/exe/' -e "runexe $base_name"
done
```

and I got the following output:

```
/otherdir/exe/ABDIRIDL:runexe ABDIRIDL
/otherdir/exe/ABIDISRI:runexe ABIDISRI
/otherdir/exe/PGAB01:runexe ADDDAY0
/otherdir/exe/PGAB01:runexe ADDDAY1
/otherdir/exe/PGAB01:runexe ADDDAY2
/otherdir/exe/PGAB01:runexe ADDDAYC1
```

How can I remove the path of the file and the string runexe and have as output:

```
ABDIRIDL   ABDIRIDL
ABIDISRI   ABIDISRI
PGAB01     ADDDAY0
PGAB01     ADDDAY1
PGAB01     ADDDAY2
PGAB01     ADDDAYC1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the output you can pipe it through `sed`. Append the following code after `done`

```
| sed -e 's#.*/##' -e 's/:runexe /\t/'
```

Instead of using a loop to search for every single file you can create a temporary file that contains all file names with `runexe` prepended and use a single `grep`.

```
for fullfile in /mydir/cdl/*.cdl; do
   file_no_path="${fullfile##*/}"
    base_name="${file_no_path%%.*}"
   echo "runexe $base_name"
done > /tmp/patterns
grep -H -orw '/otherdir/exe/' -f /tmp/patterns.txt | sed -e 's#.*/##' -e 's/:runexe /\t/'
rm /tmp/patterns
```

or better

```
find /mydir/cdl -maxdepth 1 -name '*.cdl' | sed 's#.*/\([^.]*\)\..*#runexe \1#' > /tmp/patterns
grep -H -orw '/otherdir/exe/' -f /tmp/patterns.txt | sed -e 's#.*/##' -e 's/:runexe /\t/'
rm /tmp/patterns
```

Note: The example code doesn't check for errors related to the temporary file. The code may not work as expected if you have file names with special characters.